# FormControl display value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

How to display some text in input FormControl that not equal to value of this FormControl?

For example, get some object from a server - `{id: 1, name: "Name1"}`, and set `value` of FormControl to that object or to object.id but `display value` set to object.name - "Name1".

Why i need it:

I use angular material autocomplete and it set the value of FormControl to object (from selected mat-option) and display value to string via displayWith. I want to repeate this behavior when fetch data from server for some consistency and convenience

Comment: do you want to keep id as a hidden value?In formcontrol?

Comment: i want to save object in value of FormControl but show string from this object as angular material autocomplete do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do some research for my question.

It is need to use **FormControlDirective** and its `valueAccessor.writeValue()` for set display value of input (it use renderer) or as alternative `nativeElement.value`.

And FormControl's `setValue()` with `emitModelToViewChange = false` for set FormControl value.

In template

```
<input [formControl]="ctrlF" #ctrlD="ngForm">
```

In controller

```
 @ViewChild('ctrlD', {read: FormControlDirective})
 ctrlD :FormControlDirective
 ...
 this.ctrlD.valueAccessor.writeValue("display value")
 this.ctrlD.control.setValue({foo: "foo", bar: "bar"}, {
     emitModelToViewChange: false
 })
```

[planker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/AqQ7jOeBMoDqeSyK?preview)

Answer (score 3):

You can also just use the `setValue()` twice.
First set the control value to the value that you want to display (view). Then set the control value again with the value that you want to save (model), but this time without changing the view, by using `{emitModelToViewChange: false}`

```
  this.form?.controls.country.setValue('Value to display')
  this.form?.controls.country.setValue('realValue', {emitModelToViewChange: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is use [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) inside the FormGroup. Remember that the formControl exist always. The idea is simple. Imagine you has a FormGroup

```
form=new FormGroup({
   control:new FormControl()
})

<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input [ngModel]="form.get('control').value?form.get('control').value.name:''"
       (ngModelChange)="form.get('control').setValue({id:$event})"
       [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
</form>
```

But if you're using mat-autocomplete, by defect is asigned to the formControl the object and you can also "initialize" the formControl :(. Is the second example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)

Answer (score 0):

I've subscribed to the formControl `valueChanges` observable and validate the value with a condition, and reset it if it needs to:

```js
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
  if(this.validateFormValue(value)){
    this.myForm.patchValue(this.extractValue(value))
  }
})

validateFormValue(value){
  // if condition
  return true
  // else return false
}

extractValue(value){
  // return the value you want after calculation or extraction
  return value.realValue
}
```